# Larave Livewire show input field if Others is selected

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm struggling to show input field when others is selected. In my code, the input field appears and disappears after a few second. I tried removing the `wire:model` on my selection and the input field does not disappear but I can't mount the data.

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\User;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class Create extends Component
{
    public User $user;

    public array $roles = [];

    public string $password = '';

    public array $listsForFields = [];


    public function mount(User $user, Request $request)
    {

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->initListsForFields();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.create');
    }

    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->password = $this->password;
        
        $this->user->save();
        $this->user->roles()->sync($this->roles);

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'user.name' => [
                'string',
                'required',
            ],
            'user.email' => [
                'email:rfc',
                'required',
                'unique:users,email',
            ],
            'password' => [
                'string',
                'required',
            ],
            'roles' => [
                'required',
                'array',
            ],
            'roles.*.id' => [
                'integer',
                'exists:roles,id',
            ],
            'user.locale' => [
                'string',
                'nullable',
            ],
            'user.test' => [
                'nullable',
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function initListsForFields(): void
    {
        $this->listsForFields['roles'] = Role::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
    }
}
```

Blade:

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="pt-3">

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.name') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="name">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.name') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required wire:model.defer="user.name">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.name') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.name_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.email') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="email">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.email') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required wire:model.defer="user.email">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.email') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.email_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.password') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="password">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.password') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" required wire:model.defer="password">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.password') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.password_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('roles') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="roles">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles') }}</label>
        <x-select-list class="form-control" required id="roles" name="roles" wire:model="roles" :options="$this->listsForFields['roles']" multiple />
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('roles') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.locale') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="locale">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.locale') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="locale" id="locale" wire:model.defer="user.locale">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.locale') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.locale_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.test') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.test') }}</label>
        <select onchange="testCheck(this);" class="form-control" name="test" wire:model="user.test">
            <option selected value="null" disabled>{{ trans('global.pleaseSelect') }}...</option>
            <option selected value="Yes" >Yes</option>
            <option selected value="No" >No</option>
            <option selected value="Others" >Others</option>
        </select>
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.test') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.test_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="testInput" style="display: none;" class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label required" for="testInput">Input Test</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="testInput" id="testInput" wire:model="user.test" style="text-transform:uppercase">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="mr-2 btn btn-indigo" type="submit">
            {{ trans('global.save') }}
        </button>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.users.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
            {{ trans('global.cancel') }}
        </a>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function testCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "Others") {
        document.getElementById("testInput").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("testInput").style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

if I remove `wire:model="user.test"` then the input field won't disapper after selecting `Others`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, having two root elements in your view (the form-tag and the script-tag) makes Livewire confused - you should either push the script-tag out using `@push()` and `@stack()`, but even better, we can remove it - and instead just use blade `@if`

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="pt-3">

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.name') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="name">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.name') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required wire:model.defer="user.name">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.name') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.name_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.email') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="email">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.email') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required wire:model.defer="user.email">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.email') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.email_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.password') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="password">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.password') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" required wire:model.defer="password">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.password') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.password_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('roles') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label required" for="roles">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles') }}</label>
        <x-select-list class="form-control" required id="roles" name="roles" wire:model="roles" :options="$this->listsForFields['roles']" multiple />
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('roles') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.locale') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="locale">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.locale') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="locale" id="locale" wire:model.defer="user.locale">
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.locale') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.locale_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user.test') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.test') }}</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="test" wire:model="user.test">
            <option selected value="null" disabled>{{ trans('global.pleaseSelect') }}...</option>
            <option selected value="Yes" >Yes</option>
            <option selected value="No" >No</option>
            <option selected value="Others" >Others</option>
        </select>
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('user.test') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.user.fields.test_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" @if ($user->test === 'Others') style="display: none;" @endif>
        <label class="form-label required" for="testInput">Input Test</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="testInput" id="testInput" wire:model="user.test" style="text-transform:uppercase">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="mr-2 btn btn-indigo" type="submit">
            {{ trans('global.save') }}
        </button>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.users.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
            {{ trans('global.cancel') }}
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

See how I removed the onclick event, the script-tag with the function, and replaced that `div` that should be hidden with `@if ($user->test === 'Others')`